# How to handle asynchronous tasks with actioncable subscriptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, electron, actioncable

I have an Electron application that uses actioncable to receive messages with subscriptions. I need to elaborate every message with some async function.

###### Cable connection and sending to renderer

```js
cable.subscribe(msgUpdate, {
  connected() {
    console.log("connected");
  },

  disconnected(error) {
    console.log("disconnected", error);
  },

  rejected(error) {
    console.log("rejected", error);
  },

  received(data) {
    if (data?.result?.errors?.length > 0) {
      console.log("error", data?.result?.errors);
      return;
    }
    const msg = data?.result?.data;
    win.webContents.send("sendSubs", msg);
  },
});
```

###### Electron main to renderer handling

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
  sendSubs: (callback) => (
    ipcRenderer.on('sendSubs', (_event, value) => callback(value))
  )
};
```

###### Renderer data elaboration

```js
window.api.sendSubs(async (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  let floor = await getSubsFloor(value);
  console.log(floor);
  let result = floor / value;
  console.log(result);
});
```

###### `getSubsFloor()`

```js
async function getSubsFloor(value) {
...
...
  let floor = some elaboration on value...
...
...
  console.log(floor);
  return floor;
}
```

I added `async` to the callback on the renderer to enable `await`.

What happens on the console:

- renderer => `console.log(value)` ==> OK
- renderer => `console.log(floor)` ==> `undefined`

Then after a while... and some others value OK of other msgs.

- `getSubsFloor` => `console.log(floor)` ==> OK
- renderer => `console.log(result)` ==> never reached

How to handle this situation?